# Need help on a numerical methods homework, nonlinear regression

Tags: numerical-methods, regression

Here's the question:

Employ nonlinear regression and the following set of pressure-volume data to find the best possible virial constants (A1 and A2) for the equation of state shown below. R = 82.05 mL atm/gmol K and T = 303 K.

[Data of P and V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCTeP.jpg)

Now, I'm currently trying to use the Gauss-Newton method, which uses this equation:

[Matrix Form for Gauss-Newton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIuT0.png)

Now, I've reiterated the given formula to:

$P=RT/V+ A1/V^2+A2/V^3$

So, P will act as the y-axes, and V will act as the x-axes. I've also defined the Z matrix, filling it with $\frac{\partial P}{\partial A1}$ as the first column and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial A2}$ as the second column. Here is the snippet of the code in MATLAB:

[Code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owZFj.png)

Now, I'm confused as to how do I fill the D matrix. Based on Chapra's Numerical Methods book, I found this formula from an example:

[Finding D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAsGw.png)

Now it's written in the book that the D matrix is filled with the difference between measurements and the model prediction. Now my confusion lies in how can $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a0}$ serve as the model prediction?

To sum up, here are my questions:

1. How can $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a0}$ serve as the model prediction?
2. Am I on the right track in finding the constants for A1 and A2 by using the Gauss-Newton nonlinear regression method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not since
$$P=\frac {RT}V+\frac{A_1}{V^2}+\frac{A_2}{V^3}$$ is linear with respect to $(A_1,A_2)$.

You just face a linear regression writing
$$V^3\left(P-\frac {RT}V \right)=A_1\,V+A_2$$  This can be done by hand (I did it with my phone).

Comment: Hi Claude ! We meet again. I'm beat by a few minutes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on the quantity of gaz N = gmol which is not given in the wording of the problem. In order to clarify a first linear regression is carried out :

[image]

Probably N=1 was implicit. Now we can compute A1 and A2 thanks to linear regression :

[image]

Comment: Hi Jean ! I think that we very often meet for this kind of problem ! Cheers :-)